# WPF: More than 1 items rendered as Selected in a ListBox?

Tags: wpf, templates, listbox, styles

I have a ListBox with custom styles applied. It seems sometimes, when I select a color then another (didn't press Ctrl/Shift) it seems like 2 items are selected, sometimes even more

[image]

Whats with this rendering? My XAML looks like

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ThemeColors}" SelectedValue="{Binding Color}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Margin="3" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1">
                            <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}" />
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF999999"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

## UPDATE: 14 Nov

So I followed @Meleak advice and removed all duplicates, there happen to be some. But now have another problem. Sometimes, when I select a color, the border doesn't show, the IsSelected style is not active? But the preview color updates, showing that the binding worked.

http://screenr.com/18c

Comment: Does it happen every time for those particular colors? Can you post your code behind / view models?

Comment: Yes the code behind of this app is actually the view model ... http://pastebin.com/p5McmADR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're having the exact same problem as Gishu has in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176575/selection-bug-for-listbox-where-the-list-items-are-value-types-structs-and-cont) Question. Basically, Color is a struct and not a Class and when you select a Color that is represented more than one time in your ListBox then the Selection will fail since it has no way of telling the difference between the two. Example, equal becomes true.

```
Color color1 = Colors.AliceBlue; //#FFF0F8FF
Color color2 = Color.FromArgb(255, 240, 248, 255); //#FFF0F8FF
bool equal = (color1 == color2);
```

I can think of three solutions to your problem.

1. Remove duplicates from ThemeColors
2. Change the Collection to SolidColorBrush (which is a Class and not a Struct) and Bind to Color.
3. Create your own Color class e.g. MyColor.

Comment: This has been my experience of the same problem too. I'd put a vote in for #3, and don't override equals, that way the listbox will use reference equality, which is what you want

Comment: That works, but now, I notice that sometimes when I select a color, the IsSelected style does not show up. see "UPDATE: 14 Nov"

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. I've used the ListBox you posted and when I remove all duplicates then everything works fine. I suggest you try one of the other two options as they don't have the struct problem.